# Scroll bottom only works when user scrolls back to the top of the page

Tags: jquery

The below code does not display an alert when reaching the bottom of the page it is triggered when the user scrolls back to the top of the page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      alert("bottom!");
    }
  });
</script>
<style>
  div {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
</style>

<div>
  Scroll down...
</div>
```

I have used console.log to display the values and when scrolling to the bottom of the page the values are:
`$(window).scrollTop()` = 480
`$(window).height()` = 1000
`$(document).height()` = 1000

So this code `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()` will not evaluate to `TRUE`.

When scrolling back to the top the values are:
`$(window).scrollTop()` = 0
`$(window).height()` = 1000
`$(document).height()` = 1000

So therefore this code `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()` then evaluates to TRUE !

I'm going to keep changing this code to make it trigger at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you create an [mre]?

Comment: I added a working example to your question where you can see that your jQuery code works correctly and does not show the behaviour you describe. If this is still not working for you then there is an issue elsewhere in your code which is affecting the scroll logic.

Comment: thank you I've looked at the working example and it does work as expected.  In my code I was using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of the cloudflare one and the jquery version is 3.3.1 instead of 3.6.0 but not sure that would have caused the issue.

I have got window.scroll function placed inside another window.scroll function !  I will remove the outer function and re-test

Comment: The version of jQuery is not the problem - it would be a massive bug if it was. I've updated the snippet to show it still works in 3.3.1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've created a new page and included nothing apart from the jQuery code as per my edited my question it still displays the alert message when i scroll to the top of the page.  really strange.  I'm going to try this in another browser (currently tested with Chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 ) and also on another PC.

Comment: `I have got window.scroll function placed inside another window.scroll function` that's almost certainly your problem - nested scroll handlers are rarely a good thing. It's likely that the outer scroll event is adding hundreds, if not thousands, of child scroll event handlers and they are cancelling each other out.

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan I've removed the nested scroll handler on the new "simpler" page and it sill occurs.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to show a complete example of the code you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'm going to assume the missing `>` was a typo in the question, as otherwise your code wouldn't work at all. However, the code still works correctly, and doesn't display the behaviour you describe.

Comment: yes the missing syntax was a typo.  the code that edited is exactly what I have on my new test page and the cod runs but it is opposite to my expected behaviour with an alert message at the top of the page.